# WebpackError: TypeError: merge is not a function (from plugin: gatsby-plugin-react-helmet)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gatsby, react-helmet

My Gatsby blog is deployed on Netlify. Everything was working fine, until yesterday when the deployment failed for the following reason:

**WebpackError: TypeError: merge is not a function (from plugin: gatsby-plugin-react-helmet)**

The complete deploy log is shown below:

```
11:26:10 PM: build-image version: d7b3813f01c06610bc1723ff1b22446513ee7941 (focal)
11:26:10 PM: build-image tag: v4.14.3
11:26:10 PM: buildbot version: be0925a1b4e8f8d2c5a767f3e0decf8856cad273
11:26:11 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
11:26:11 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
11:26:11 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
11:26:11 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
11:26:11 PM: git clone https://github.com/sundaray/hemanta.io
11:26:12 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
11:26:13 PM: Parsing package.json dependencies
11:26:14 PM: Starting build script
11:26:14 PM: Installing dependencies
11:26:14 PM: Python version set to 2.7
11:26:14 PM: Downloading and installing node v12.18.0...
11:26:14 PM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.18.0/node-v12.18.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
11:26:15 PM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
11:26:15 PM: Checksums matched!
11:26:16 PM: Now using node v12.18.0 (npm v6.14.4)
11:26:16 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
11:26:16 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
11:26:16 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.1, read from environment
11:26:16 PM: Required ruby-2.7.1 is not installed - installing.
11:26:17 PM: Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
11:26:17 PM: Found remote file https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/ubuntu/20.04/x86_64/ruby-2.7.1.tar.bz2
11:26:17 PM: Checking requirements for ubuntu.
11:26:17 PM: Requirements installation successful.
11:26:17 PM: ruby-2.7.1 - #configure
11:26:17 PM: ruby-2.7.1 - #download
11:26:17 PM: ruby-2.7.1 - #validate archive
11:26:20 PM: ruby-2.7.1 - #extract
11:26:22 PM: ruby-2.7.1 - #validate binary
11:26:22 PM: ruby-2.7.1 - #setup
11:26:23 PM: ruby-2.7.1 - #gemset created /opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1@global
11:26:23 PM: ruby-2.7.1 - #importing gemset /opt/buildhome/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems........................................
11:26:23 PM: ruby-2.7.1 - #generating global wrappers........
11:26:23 PM: ruby-2.7.1 - #gemset created /opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1
11:26:23 PM: ruby-2.7.1 - #importing gemsetfile /opt/buildhome/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems evaluated to empty gem list
11:26:23 PM: ruby-2.7.1 - #generating default wrappers........
11:26:23 PM: Using /opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1
11:26:24 PM: Using ruby version 2.7.1
11:26:24 PM: Using PHP version 8.0
11:26:24 PM: No npm workspaces detected
11:26:24 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
11:26:24 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
11:26:24 PM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 6.14.4
11:26:29 PM: npm WARN deprecated multer@1.4.4: Multer 1.x is affected by CVE-2022-24434. This is fixed in v1.4.4-lts.1 which drops support for versions of Node.js before 6. Please upgrade to at least Node.js 6 and version 1.4.4-lts.1 of Multer. If you need support for older versions of Node.js, we are open to accepting patches that would fix the CVE on the main 1.x release line, whilst maintaining compatibility with Node.js 0.10.
11:26:29 PM: npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
11:26:30 PM: npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
11:26:34 PM: npm WARN deprecated gatsby-recipes@0.25.0: gatsby-recipes has been removed from gatsby/gatsby-cli >=4.5.0. Update to gatsby@latest/gatsby-cli@latest to use versions without gatsby-recipes. This package will no longer receive updates.
11:26:36 PM: npm WARN deprecated async-cache@1.1.0: No longer maintained. Use [lru-cache](http://npm.im/lru-cache) version 7.6 or higher, and provide an asynchronous `fetchMethod` option.
11:26:36 PM: npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
11:26:37 PM: npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
11:26:40 PM: npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
11:26:40 PM: npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
11:26:43 PM: npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
11:26:43 PM: npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
11:26:43 PM: npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
11:26:44 PM: npm WARN deprecated subscriptions-transport-ws@0.9.19: The `subscriptions-transport-ws` package is no longer maintained. We recommend you use `graphql-ws` instead. For help migrating Apollo software to `graphql-ws`, see https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#switching-from-subscriptions-transport-ws    For general help using `graphql-ws`, see https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/README.md
11:26:47 PM: npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
11:26:49 PM: npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
11:26:49 PM: npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
11:26:49 PM: npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
11:40:12 PM: > sharp@0.29.3 install /opt/build/repo/node_modules/sharp
11:40:12 PM: > (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
11:40:13 PM: sharp: Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.11.3/libvips-8.11.3-linux-x64.tar.br
11:40:14 PM: > @fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types@0.2.36 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types
11:40:14 PM: > node attribution.js
11:40:14 PM: Font Awesome Free 0.2.36 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com
11:40:14 PM: License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free (Icons: CC BY 4.0, Fonts: SIL OFL 1.1, Code: MIT License)
11:40:14 PM: > core-js@3.26.0 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/core-js
11:40:14 PM: > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
11:40:14 PM: > core-js-pure@3.26.0 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/core-js-pure
11:40:14 PM: > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
11:40:15 PM: > es5-ext@0.10.62 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/es5-ext
11:40:15 PM: >  node -e "try{require('./_postinstall')}catch(e){}" || exit 0
11:40:15 PM: > gatsby-telemetry@2.14.0 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby-telemetry
11:40:15 PM: > node src/postinstall.js || true
11:40:15 PM: > gatsby-cli@3.14.2 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/gatsby-cli
11:40:15 PM: > node scripts/postinstall.js
11:40:15 PM: > @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core@1.2.36 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
11:40:15 PM: > node attribution.js
11:40:15 PM: Font Awesome Free 1.2.36 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com
11:40:15 PM: License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free (Icons: CC BY 4.0, Fonts: SIL OFL 1.1, Code: MIT License)
11:40:15 PM: > @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons@5.15.4 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
11:40:15 PM: > node attribution.js
11:40:15 PM: Font Awesome Free 5.15.4 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com
11:40:15 PM: License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free (Icons: CC BY 4.0, Fonts: SIL OFL 1.1, Code: MIT License)
11:40:15 PM: > gatsby@3.14.6 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby
11:40:15 PM: > node scripts/postinstall.js
11:40:16 PM: npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
11:40:16 PM: npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for gatsby-remark-katex@6.24.0: wanted: {"node":">=14.15.0"} (current: {"node":"12.18.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
11:40:16 PM: npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: gatsby-remark-katex@6.24.0
11:40:16 PM: npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for react-hook-form@7.39.3: wanted: {"node":">=12.22.0"} (current: {"node":"12.18.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
11:40:16 PM: npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: react-hook-form@7.39.3
11:40:16 PM: npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
11:40:16 PM: npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
11:40:16 PM: npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for type-fest@2.19.0: wanted: {"node":">=12.20"} (current: {"node":"12.18.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
11:40:16 PM: npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: type-fest@2.19.0
11:40:16 PM: npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for gatsby-plugin-postcss@5.24.0: wanted: {"node":">=14.15.0"} (current: {"node":"12.18.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
11:40:16 PM: npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: gatsby-plugin-postcss@5.24.0
11:40:16 PM: npm WARN bootstrap@5.2.2 requires a peer of @popperjs/core@^2.11.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
11:40:16 PM: npm WARN gatsby-plugin-typography@3.14.0 requires a peer of typography@^0.16.0 || ^1.0.0-alpha.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
11:40:16 PM: npm WARN gatsby-remark-katex@6.24.0 requires a peer of gatsby@^4.0.0-next but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
11:40:16 PM: npm WARN gatsby-remark-katex@6.24.0 requires a peer of katex@^0.13.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
11:40:16 PM: npm WARN gatsby-remark-reading-time@1.1.0 requires a peer of gatsby@^2.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
11:40:16 PM: npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@6.0.0 requires a peer of babel-eslint@^10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
11:40:16 PM: npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
11:40:16 PM: npm WARN ts-node@9.1.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
11:40:16 PM: npm WARN acorn-import-assertions@1.8.0 requires a peer of acorn@^8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
11:40:16 PM: npm WARN gatsby-plugin-postcss@5.24.0 requires a peer of gatsby@^4.0.0-next but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
11:40:16 PM: added 2214 packages from 1135 contributors and audited 2219 packages in 831.887s
11:40:17 PM: 363 packages are looking for funding
11:40:17 PM:   run `npm fund` for details
11:40:17 PM: found 38 vulnerabilities (16 moderate, 16 high, 6 critical)
11:40:17 PM:   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
11:40:17 PM: NPM modules installed
11:40:17 PM: Creating package sha
11:40:17 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
11:40:17 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
11:40:17 PM: Installing Go version 1.14.4 (requested 1.14.4)
11:40:21 PM: unset GOOS;
11:40:21 PM: unset GOARCH;
11:40:21 PM: export GOROOT='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.14.4.linux.amd64';
11:40:21 PM: export PATH="/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.14.4.linux.amd64/bin:${PATH}";
11:40:21 PM: go version >&2;
11:40:21 PM: export GIMME_ENV="/opt/buildhome/.gimme/env/go1.14.4.linux.amd64.env"
11:40:21 PM: go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
11:40:21 PM: Detected 1 framework(s)
11:40:21 PM: "gatsby" at version "3.14.6"
11:40:21 PM: Installing missing commands
11:40:21 PM: Verify run directory
11:40:23 PM: ​
11:40:23 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
11:40:23 PM:   Netlify Build                                                 
11:40:23 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
11:40:23 PM: ​
11:40:23 PM: ❯ Version
11:40:23 PM:   @netlify/build 28.1.13
11:40:23 PM: ​
11:40:23 PM: ❯ Flags
11:40:23 PM:   baseRelDir: true
11:40:23 PM:   buildId: 63712fb964e5d200085e449c
11:40:23 PM:   deployId: 63712fb964e5d200085e449e
11:40:23 PM: ​
11:40:23 PM: ❯ Current directory
11:40:23 PM:   /opt/build/repo
11:40:23 PM: ​
11:40:23 PM: ❯ Config file
11:40:23 PM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
11:40:23 PM: ​
11:40:23 PM: ❯ Context
11:40:23 PM:   production
11:40:23 PM: ​
11:40:23 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
11:40:23 PM:   1. Build command from Netlify app                             
11:40:23 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
11:40:23 PM: ​
11:40:23 PM: $ npm run build
11:40:23 PM: > gatsby-starter-hello-world@0.1.0 build /opt/build/repo
11:40:23 PM: > gatsby build
11:40:24 PM: warning Plugin gatsby-plugin-postcss is not compatible with your gatsby version 3.14.6 - It requires gatsby@^4.0.0-next
11:40:25 PM: warning Plugin gatsby-remark-reading-time is not compatible with your gatsby version 3.14.6 - It requires gatsby@^2.0.0
11:40:25 PM: warning Plugin gatsby-plugin-postcss is not compatible with your gatsby version 3.14.6 - It requires gatsby@^4.0.0-next
11:40:25 PM: warning Plugin gatsby-remark-reading-time is not compatible with your gatsby version 3.14.6 - It requires gatsby@^2.0.0
11:40:25 PM: success open and validate gatsby-configs, load plugins - 0.580s
11:40:25 PM: success onPreInit - 0.002s
11:40:25 PM: success initialize cache - 0.031s
11:40:25 PM: success copy gatsby files - 0.034s
11:40:25 PM: success Compiling Gatsby Functions - 0.159s
11:40:25 PM: success onPreBootstrap - 0.166s
11:40:26 PM: success createSchemaCustomization - 0.411s
11:40:34 PM: success Checking for changed pages - 0.000s
11:40:34 PM: success source and transform nodes - 8.299s
11:40:35 PM: success building schema - 0.396s
11:40:35 PM: success createPages - 0.158s
11:40:35 PM: success createPagesStatefully - 0.064s
11:40:35 PM: info Total nodes: 2699, SitePage nodes: 541 (use --verbose for breakdown)
11:40:35 PM: success Checking for changed pages - 0.000s
11:40:35 PM: success update schema - 0.099s
11:40:35 PM: success onPreExtractQueries - 0.000s
11:40:35 PM: success extract queries from components - 0.305s
11:40:35 PM: success write out redirect data - 0.000s
11:40:35 PM: success onPostBootstrap - 0.000s
11:40:35 PM: info bootstrap finished - 12.272s
11:40:35 PM: success run static queries - 0.003s - 1/1 324.33/s
11:41:40 PM: success run page queries - 64.400s - 541/541 8.40/s
11:41:40 PM: success write out requires - 0.007s
11:41:56 PM: success Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles - 16.351s
11:41:56 PM: success Rewriting compilation hashes - 0.048s
11:41:56 PM: success Writing page-data.json files to public directory - 0.440s - 541/541 1229.54/s
11:42:01 PM: success Building HTML renderer - 2.486s
11:42:02 PM: error Page data from page-data.json for the failed page "/review-January-2022/": {
11:42:02 PM:   "componentChunkName": "component---src-templates-blog-post-js",
11:42:02 PM:   "path": "/review-January-2022/",
11:42:02 PM:   "result": {
11:42:02 PM:     "data": {
11:42:02 PM:       "markdownRemark": {
11:42:02 PM:         "html": "<p>In January, I achieved my target of writing 10 blog posts.</p>\n<p>My original plan was to build a developer blog using Gatsby. Even though I started following the tutorial on the official Gatsby site, I veered off course. I practiced a little b...",
11:42:02 PM:         "frontmatter": {
11:42:02 PM:           "title": "Review - January, 2022",
11:42:02 PM:           "date": "2022-02-01"
11:42:02 PM:         }
11:42:02 PM:       }
11:42:02 PM:     },
11:42:02 PM:     "pageContext": {
11:42:02 PM:       "slug": "/review-January-2022/",
11:42:02 PM:       "prev": {
11:42:02 PM:         "fields": {
11:42:02 PM:           "slug": "/define-python-functions-with-unlimited-keyword-arguments-using-kwargs/"
11:42:02 PM:         },
11:42:02 PM:         "frontmatter": {
11:42:02 PM:           "modules": null
11:42:02 PM:         }
11:42:02 PM:       },
11:42:02 PM:       "next": {
11:42:02 PM:         "fields": {
11:42:02 PM:           "slug": "/check-the-type-of-a-python-variable/"
11:42:02 PM:         },
11:42:02 PM:         "frontmatter": {
11:42:02 PM:           "modules": null
11:42:02 PM:         }
11:42:02 PM:       }
11:42:02 PM:     }
11:42:02 PM:   },
11:42:02 PM:   "staticQueryHashes": [
11:42:02 PM:     "3159585216"
11:42:02 PM:   ]
11:42:02 PM: }
11:42:02 PM: failed Building static HTML for pages - 1.409s
11:42:02 PM: error Building static HTML failed for path "/review-January-2022/"
11:42:02 PM: 
11:42:02 PM:   100 |   }
11:42:02 PM:   101 |
11:42:02 PM: > 102 |   return merge(a, b, { arrayMerge: combineMerge })
11:42:02 PM:       |          ^
11:42:02 PM:   103 | }
11:42:02 PM:   104 |
11:42:02 PM:   105 | export default async function staticPage({
11:42:02 PM: 
11:42:02 PM:   WebpackError: TypeError: merge is not a function (from plugin: gatsby-plugin-r  eact-helmet)
11:42:02 PM:   
11:42:02 PM:   - static-entry.js:102 
11:42:02 PM:     gatsby-starter-hello-world/.cache/static-entry.js:102:10
11:42:02 PM:   
11:42:02 PM:   - static-entry.js:166 
11:42:02 PM:     gatsby-starter-hello-world/.cache/static-entry.js:166:24
11:42:02 PM:   
11:42:02 PM:   - gatsby-ssr.js:17 
11:42:02 PM:     [gatsby-starter-hello-world]/[gatsby-plugin-react-helmet]/gatsby-ssr.js:17:5  
11:42:02 PM:   - api-runner-ssr.js:52 
11:42:02 PM:     gatsby-starter-hello-world/.cache/api-runner-ssr.js:52:22
11:42:02 PM:   
11:42:02 PM:   - api-runner-ssr.js:45 
11:42:02 PM:     gatsby-starter-hello-world/.cache/api-runner-ssr.js:45:11
11:42:02 PM:   
11:42:02 PM:   - static-entry.js:307 
11:42:02 PM:     gatsby-starter-hello-world/.cache/static-entry.js:307:5
11:42:02 PM:   
11:42:02 PM:   - index.es.js:121 
11:42:02 PM:     [gatsby-starter-hello-world]/[@fortawesome]/free-solid-svg-icons/index.es.js    :121:1
11:42:02 PM:   
11:42:02 PM: 
11:42:02 PM: not finished Caching JavaScript and CSS webpack compilation - 6.127s
11:42:02 PM: not finished Caching HTML renderer compilation - 1.518s
11:42:02 PM: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
11:42:02 PM: npm ERR! errno 1
11:42:02 PM: npm ERR! gatsby-starter-hello-world@0.1.0 build: `gatsby build`
11:42:02 PM: npm ERR! Exit status 1
11:42:02 PM: npm ERR!
11:42:02 PM: npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-starter-hello-world@0.1.0 build script.
11:42:02 PM: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
11:42:02 PM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
11:42:02 PM: npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2022-11-13T18_12_02_730Z-debug.log
11:42:02 PM: ​
11:42:02 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
11:42:02 PM:   "build.command" failed                                        
11:42:02 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
11:42:02 PM: ​
11:42:02 PM:   Error message
11:42:02 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
11:42:02 PM: ​
11:42:02 PM:   Error location
11:42:02 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
11:42:02 PM:   npm run build
11:42:02 PM: ​
11:42:02 PM:   Resolved config
11:42:02 PM:   build:
11:42:02 PM:     command: npm run build
11:42:02 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
11:42:02 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/public
11:42:02 PM:     publishOrigin: ui
11:42:03 PM: Caching artifacts
11:42:03 PM: Started saving node modules
11:42:03 PM: Finished saving node modules
11:42:03 PM: Started saving build plugins
11:42:03 PM: Finished saving build plugins
11:42:03 PM: Started saving pip cache
11:42:03 PM: Finished saving pip cache
11:42:03 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
11:42:03 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
11:42:03 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
11:42:03 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
11:42:03 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
11:42:03 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
11:42:03 PM: Started saving rust rustup cache
11:42:03 PM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
11:42:03 PM: Started saving go dependencies
11:42:03 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
11:42:08 PM: Cached ruby version 2.7.1
11:42:08 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
11:42:08 PM: Creating deploy upload records
11:42:08 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
11:42:08 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-2)
11:42:08 PM: Finished processing build request in 15m58.036179676s
```

What do I need to do to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Found this on GitHub:

> "Another temporary solution is adding explicitely `deepmerge` dependency to your project."

Hope it helps.

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/33274